# ternary operator for drawable in layout expression

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-databinding

This is my `fragment_setting.xml`.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:background="@{settingVm.isNotiOn ? @drawable/btn_on_mid : @drawable/btn_off_mid}"
    android:onClick="@{()->settingVm.changeBtnStatus()}"
    android:text="@string/on"
    android:textOff="on"
    android:textOn="on"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:background="@{settingVm.isNotiOn ? @drawable/btn_off_mid : @drawable/btn_on_mid}"
    android:onClick="@{()-> settingVm.changeBtnStatus()}"
    android:text="@string/off"
    android:textOff="off"
    android:textOn="off"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is my `SettingViewModel`

```
class SettingViewModel(handler: SettingHandler) : ViewModel() {
    var handler = handler
    var isNotiOn: Boolean? = true
    var visibility = View.VISIBLE

    init {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
            Timber.d("start")
        }
    }

    fun onBackBtnPressed() {
        Timber.d("onBackBtnPressed()")
        handler.onBackBtnPressed()
    }

    fun showLogoutDialogue() {
        Timber.d("showLogoutDialogue()")
        handler.showLogoutDialogue()
    }

    fun changeBtnStatus(){
        Timber.d("changeBtnStatus()")
        handler.changeBtnStatus()
    }
}
```

And this is my `SettingFragment`

```
...
        val spUtil = SharedPreferenceUtil(activity!!)
        when (spUtil.isNotificationOn) {
            false -> {
                binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn = false
            }
            else -> {
                binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn = true
            }
        }
...
    override fun changeBtnStatus() {
        // TODO: Set real notification setting.

        val spUtil = SharedPreferenceUtil(activity!!)
        when (binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn) {
            true -> {
                binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn = false
                spUtil.isNotificationOn = false
            }
            else -> {
                binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn = true
                spUtil.isNotificationOn = true
            }
        }
    }
```

What's the problem??? I am not using two way binding and the ternary operator like `@={}`. But I reckon I should use two way binding because it is not a constant value. And I have two images correctly.

Someone says I should not use `is` prefix because it might generate `getter` and `setter`. So, I even tried removing it and define `has` prefix or just `NotiOn` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MutableLiveData in order to change the status and observe that inside the fragment to get live update and you can change the drawable values according to this LiveData

ViewModel.kt

```
class GuestViewModel @Inject constructor(val repo: GuestRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val guest = MutableLiveData<Guest>()
    val guestLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}
```

Fragment.kt

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final TestViewModel viewModel =          ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(TestViewModel.class);
    viewModel.guestLoading.observe(this, it -> {
         //Do something
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code once ## Your XML should be in the code is look like this

```
<ToggleButton 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:button="@{settingVm.isNotiOn ? @drawable/btn_on_mid : @drawable/btn_off_mid}"/>
```

and the following java code you can reduce and get the result in proper form. please use this code on fragment class.

```
val spUtil = SharedPreferenceUtil(activity!!) tbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> spUtil.isNotificationOn = isChecked binding!!.settingVm!!.isNotiOn = isChecked }
```

========================================================================